# How to keep liquibase changeset md5 hash after version update?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase

Recently we updated liquibase from version 3.8.9 to 4.6.1 in a Spring Boot application.
On our database we already have a lot of applied changesets with correctly set md5sum values.

After the update all md5sum values were gone in the database (replaced by `NULL`). However we still want to have the md5sum values for old changesets. The database we use is Postgres.

What we found out until now:

1. check how everything behaves on a new database

When liquibase is executed against an empty database all changesets get a new md5sum value. What we recognized is that the filenames changed between the versions. In the old version the filename was like `classpath:db/some_changeset.xml` whereas in the new version the filename is `db/some_changeset.xml`.

2. with the finding of 1. we updated our changesets

In our changesets we now added the `logicalFilePath` attribute. For the example in 1 we added `logicalFilePath="classpath:db/some_changeset.xml"`. The problem with this approach is that it recalculates the md5sum values for all old entries. The execution doesn't fail but everything ends up in having a new md5 hash. At least from that point on the hash values are correctly validated if a changeset changes after it has been applied to the database.

We thought that md5 hashes should be constant over different versions. So how can we keep the old values (in the best case without touching old changeset files) and then go on with new changes?

Comment: Have you been able to get an answer to this? 

The release notes are available on the [Liquibase Docs site.](https://docs.liquibase.com/release-notes/home.html) These may help provide context, as it could be a change in one of the releases between 3.8.9 and 4.6.1.  We are on 4.10 now, so if it was a bug, updating should resolve it. - https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/maintenance/calculate-checksum.html
- https://www.liquibase.com/blog/what-affects-changeset-checksums

Comment: Since we had the need to update we took a different approach on updating.